# How should I compare elements at every position in two lists using numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose there are two lists with the same dimension, let's say `[0,1,2,2]` and `[0,1,2,2]`. How should I compare two elements at every position and return a matrix which, in this case, is `[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]]`?
i.e. `f(x,y)=1 if x=y else 0`, and x,y are come from the above two lists respectively.

Already tried the for-loop block with python, which is rather slow when dealing with large lists.

Is there any efficient way of handling this problem with numpy instead of using codes below:

```py
for i in list_1:
   for j in list_2:
      1 if i==j else 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.equal` to compare the elements and use `np.where` to convert it into 1 or 0.:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,2,2])
b = np.array([0,1,2,2])

z = np.where(np.equal(a, b[:,np.newaxis]), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Or as @Onyambu suggested, you can do

```
z = (a==b[:,None]).astype(int)
```

Comment: you can also add `(a==b[:,None]).astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. And I also found another way to apply np.equal.outer().

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, I hope this would help.

```
print([1 if i==j else 0 for i,j in zip([0,1,2,2],[0,1,0,2])])
```

Ouput :

```
[1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Output op wants is `[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1]]`